# change first line of a file using bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

I need to change a single line in a file. It is always in the first line of the file.

It looks like:

```
h\tn0   n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7  n8  n9  hilu    cjt 1   1000000
```

there is a tab in all gaps except after the h.

I would need to re-transform the line into

```
h  n1   n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7  n8  n9  
hilu    cjt 1   1000000
```

at the beginning o the line the \t thing and n0 needs to go and there needs to be a tab between h and n1. Then a newline needs to start before *hilu* but there should be no additional tab after n9

Ideally I would just feed my file to the script and it would not require writing an intermediate script to fill.

is there maybe an efficient version in Perl or python or so? I thought about R but then there are 1000 of lines in the file and only the first lien needs be changed...

tried to use the solution from [jahid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31241310/3744681) to run it from r with

```
> system(paste("sed -r \'1s/(.*)\t(REGION.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//\'","arg_t1")) 
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```

with the suggest from the comm I get

```
> system(paste("sed -r \"1s/(.*)\t(REGION.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//\"","arg_t1")) 
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Why have you give your question a Perl tag?

Comment: @Borodin I guess the "is there maybe an efficient version in perl or python or so?" in the question addresses that?

Comment: @Borodin presumably because he or she wants to do this in Perl.

Comment: yes think it might just be that there is a efficient version in this language...I knwo that the solution I think about in other languages woul require reading the whole file in which is rubish

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: `sed '1s/\\t/\t/' yourfile` ?

Comment: @Сухой27 out of curiosity: why do you remove [perl] tag in questions like this?

Comment: @fedorqui question doesn't provide any of the perl code, and subject is clearly stating `using bash`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `Ideally I would just feed my file to the script and it would not require writing an intermediate script to fill.`? Do you mean an intermediate, temp output file or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bash job, it's a job for ed or sed. For instance, `sed -i -e '1s/\\tn0\s*/\t/' -e '1s/\s*\(hilu\)/\n\1/' filename` can do this. As Perl's foundation is a merging of shell, awk and sed, it can also be used similarly.

The editing itself isn't efficient because POSIX file semantics do not permit inserting or removing data, only (over)writing or truncating. This command therefore copies the file, with only the beginning altered. If done as part of a pipeline (just remove -i to output to stdout) it's practically zero cost. Also, with thousands of lines of data that's still pretty small by today's standards.

Comment: Note that editing a file in-place is a *great* way to end up with filesystem corruption. *Always* implement read-modify-write of a file by writing to a separate file and then atomically renaming it (`sed` does this with a temporary file to implement `-i`), unless you are implementing a database (and please don't).

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` (with Extended Regex):

```
sed -r '1s/(.*)\t(hilu.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//' file
```

To change the file inplace:

```
sed -r --in-place '1s/(.*)\t(hilu.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//' file
```

Comment: is it maybe possbile to make this accept a list of files and then to perform the thing on all of them and name them all exactly as the input

Comment: somehwo I also end up with two tabs between the first word and the next entry (t1)...ould you maybe change that?

Comment: @ktoui sorry about that, I was replacing `\tn0` with a `tab`. It's fixed now.

Comment: tried to loop through and exec from within r with
> system(paste("sed -r --in-place \'1s/(.*)\t(REGION.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//\'","arg_t1")
+ )
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
>

Comment: then i get > system(paste("sed -r \"1s/(.*)\t(REGION.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//\"","arg_t1")) 
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @ktoui do you really need to escape single quote there ?

Comment: @ktoui How about: `system(paste("sed -r '1s/(.*)\t(REGION.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//'","arg_t1")` i.e unescaped single quote...

Comment: do get the same...> system(paste("sed -r '1s/(.*)\t(REGION.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//'","arg_t1")
+ )
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @ktoui may be there are some other special chars that need to be escaped for r. I am not quite acquainted with r, so not much of a help there..

Answer (score -1):

To your example it could be something like this using **Python**. But also you need to open file and fetch first line inside variable line.

```
import re

line = 'h\tn0   n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7  n8  n9  hilu    cjt 1   1000000'
line = re.sub('n9\s*','n9\n', re.sub('h.+n1', 'h\tn1', line))
print line
```

Comment: you might want to give the OP a clue as to which dialect of perl/bash/awk this is...