# R system command

Tags: r, bash

I would like to execute this system command in R

```
sed -r '1s/(.*)\t(hilu.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//' file
```

My try

```
system(paste("sed -r \'1s/(.*)\t(hilu.*)/\1\n\2/;1s/\\t[^[:space:]]+//\'","file")) 
# sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```

Does that mean it is just not working because of my OS? I am on Ubuntu 14

The question was brought up here
[change first line of a file using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240753/change-first-line-of-a-file-using-bash/31241310?noredirect=1#comment50522195_31241310)

Comment: It's just a matter of proper escaping: `system("sed -r '1s/(.*)\\t(hilu.*)/\\1\\n\\2/;1s/\\\\t[^[:space:]]+//' FILE")` (which you can translate into your `paste` setup)

Comment: but i wouldneed to change the fil input ina lop...